# How to implement record ordering according to user preferences?

Tags: sql, database

I'm storing records in an SQL table and want to display them in my application according to the user-defined order. An obvious approach is to add an 'Order' column, but this means if a user moves an item from position 50 to position 10, all intermediate records need to be updated. How can I implement this in a clean way that doesn't require editing all records when a user moves an item from one position to another?

Comment: Same items ordered differently (at least potentially) for each user?

Comment: It's a single-user db/application.

Comment: If it is "single user", only one user defines the order, and yes, if the user changes the order, you should update the records to reflect the new order.

Comment: This could potentially become an expensive thing to do, no?

Comment: It's more complicated, but with an eye toward multiuser implementation you could consider maintaining a linked list in a separate table. The table holds user id, current record id, previous record id, and next record id. Then, if user moves record from one position to another, you need only update the records that are affected. Of course, querying in the correct order requires some thought and an extra join. This is arguably less efficient than maintaining an order column though.

Comment: Why not just build the sort order into your application logic? Otherwise you'll need to take the user preference and use it to dynamically build an ORDER BY clause in the SQL you are running

Comment: I want to store the user-defined ordering of items somewhere, so I can retrieve this information later.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: This is mostly theoretical question hence I didn't mention specific engine. I mostly use SQL Server, PostgreSQL and SQLite

Answer (score 0):

I attempted an approach in which the order column would be a floating-point number instead of an integer. In this setup, the value of the moved item would be positioned between its two nearest neighbours.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE UserOrderingSp @moving_id INT, @before_id INT, @after_id INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @before_id_value FLOAT = ISNULL((SELECT UserOrder FROM #ValuesTemporaryTable WHERE StartPosition = @before_id), 0);
    DECLARE @after_id_value FLOAT = ISNULL((SELECT UserOrder FROM #ValuesTemporaryTable WHERE StartPosition = @after_id), (SELECT MAX(UserOrder)+1 FROM #ValuesTemporaryTable));

    UPDATE #ValuesTemporaryTable
    SET UserOrder = (@before_id_value + @after_id_value) / 2
    WHERE StartPosition = @moving_id;
END
```

```sql
--TEST
CREATE TABLE #ValuesTemporaryTable (StartPosition int, UserOrder float);

INSERT INTO #ValuesTemporaryTable (StartPosition, UserOrder) values (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3);
SELECT * FROM #ValuesTemporaryTable order by UserOrder;

-- move 3 between 1 and 2 (pos. 2)
EXEC UserOrderingSp 3, 1, 2;
SELECT * FROM #ValuesTemporaryTable order by UserOrder;

-- add new item at the end (pos. 4)
INSERT INTO #ValuesTemporaryTable (StartPosition, UserOrder) values (4, (SELECT MAX(UserOrder)+1 FROM #ValuesTemporaryTable));
SELECT * FROM #ValuesTemporaryTable order by UserOrder;

-- move 4 between 1 and 3 (pos. 2)
EXEC UserOrderingSp 4, 1, 3;
SELECT * FROM #ValuesTemporaryTable order by UserOrder;

-- move 1 between 4 and 3 (pos. 2)
EXEC UserOrderingSp 1, 4, 3;
SELECT * FROM #ValuesTemporaryTable order by UserOrder;

-- move 3 to the beginning (pos. 1)
EXEC UserOrderingSp 3, null, 4;
SELECT * FROM #ValuesTemporaryTable order by UserOrder;

-- CLEAN UP
DROP TABLE #ValuesTemporaryTable;
```

If the client knew the order values, they could calculate the 'after' order themselves, which would further simplify the Stored Procedure. Beyond the issues with mathematical operations involving floating-point numbers at higher precision levels, are there any other obvious flaws with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider a simple graph approach to the problem since this is pretty much what they are designed for. First, instead of an "Order" field in your table, place a "Next" field to point to each records child.  The field def would be:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GraphDemo](
    [UID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Next] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](24) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Next, you'll insert new records in the end by default. To make this simple, use a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_AddPerson](@Name varchar(24))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @ThisPersonID int
    DECLARE @LastPersonID int
    SELECT @LastPersonID=UID FROM GraphDemo WHERE [Next]=0
    IF @LastPersonID IS NULL 
    BEGIN
        SET @LastPersonID = 0
    END
    INSERT INTO GraphDemo ([Next], [Name]) VALUES (0, @Name)
    SET @ThisPersonID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    IF @LastPersonID > 0 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE GraphDemo SET [Next]=@ThisPersonID WHERE UID=@LastPersonID
    END
    SELECT @ThisPersonID AS NewUID
END
```

Next, you'll want a stored procedure for re-assigning a node to a new parent. This looks way more complex than it is. If you create a little chart, you'll see that it is really just swapping the "Next" pointers. This means that your time complexity for UPDATES is always just a small fixed number rather than scaling with the size of your database. Here's the stored procedure. Really, the bulk of the work is done by the last block. All the others handle special cases.

```
-- Move one node (the child) to be after another (the parent)
ALTER PROCEDURE up_ChangePosition(@ChildNode int, @ParentNode int)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    -- Ensure that both nodes exist, which guarantees at least 2 nodes.
    DECLARE @NodeCount INT
    SELECT @NodeCount=COUNT('b') FROM GraphDemo WHERE UID IN (@ChildNode, @ParentNode)
    IF @NodeCount < 2 RETURN 0;  -- 0 records affected since there was only 1 or no records.

    DECLARE @OldPriorUID INT, @OldNextUID INT
    SELECT @OldPriorUID=[UID] FROM GraphDemo WHERE [Next]=@ChildNode
    SELECT @OldNextUID=[Next] FROM GraphDemo WHERE [UID]=@ChildNode

    -- We want to move this node to the beginning
    IF @ParentNode = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @OldPriorUID IS NULL RETURN 0;  -- We're already at the beginning.
        DECLARE @OldHeadUID INT  -- The first node in our order
        SELECT TOP 1 @OldHeadUID=[UID] FROM GraphDemo WHERE ([UID] NOT IN (SELECT [Next] FROM GraphDemo))
        -- Patch around the former position of this node
        UPDATE GraphDemo SET [Next]=@OldNextUID WHERE [UID] = @OldPriorUID
        -- Now point this node to the old head node...making it the new head.
        UPDATE GraphDemo SET [Next]=@OldHeadUID WHERE [UID] = @ChildNode
        RETURN 1
    END

    DECLARE @NewPriorUID INT, @NewNextUID INT 
    SELECT @NewPriorUID=[UID] FROM GraphDemo WHERE [Next]=@ParentNode
    SELECT @NewNextUID=[Next] FROM GraphDemo WHERE [UID]=@ParentNode
    IF @OldPriorUID IS NULL  -- This node was the first in the list so there was no record pointing to it. Easy case.
    BEGIN
        UPDATE GraphDemo SET [Next]=@ChildNode WHERE UID=@ParentNode
        -- Make selected node point to the one that its new parent used to point to
        UPDATE GraphDemo SET [Next]=@NewNextUID WHERE UID=@ChildNode  -- Next may be zero (end of list)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- The node that used to point to our selected node now points to that which the selected node pointed to
        UPDATE GraphDemo SET [Next]=@OldNextUID WHERE UID=@OldPriorUID  
        -- Make the parent now point to the selected node 
        UPDATE GraphDemo SET [Next]=@ChildNode WHERE UID=@ParentNode
        -- The node the parent pointed to is now the child of the selected node
        UPDATE GraphDemo SET [Next]=@NewNextUID WHERE UID=@ChildNode  -- Next may be zero (end of list)
    END
    RETURN 1
END
```

The last part is to pull your list in order. Fortunately, SQL gives us the amazing Recursive CTE (Common Table Expression) to solve exactly this problem. The query is:

```
WITH GraphCTE(UID, Next, Name, OrderNumber) AS (
    SELECT UID, Next, Name, 1 AS OrderNumber
    FROM GraphDemo
    WHERE UID NOT IN (SELECT [Next] FROM GraphDemo)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT g.UID, g.Next, g.Name, OrderNumber + 1 FROM GraphDemo g INNER JOIN GraphCTE cte ON cte.Next = g.UID
)
SELECT UID, Next, Name, OrderNumber
FROM GraphCTE
ORDER BY OrderNumber;
```

Again, this may look complex but it really makes a lot of sense once you get your head wrapped around it. Plus, it has the advantage of packing up the Add and Move operations in stored procedures and then giving you a simple query to find your list - one purpose-built by SQL for exactly this case.

I would not recommend an approach based on floating point numbers. It is tempting and, I have to admit, I first thought of doing that. But, still, there are edge cases and efficiency issues that just make me shy away from it.